# Play Framework 2.3 jvm memory on run

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to increase Jvm memory of my application but doesn't matter what I use I get 256Mb as max memory. To see the max memory I am using

```
val instance = Runtime.getRuntime();
val  mb = 1024 * 1024;
val maxm = ("Max Memory: " + instance.maxMemory() / mb);
```

I tried to to run the app with...

```
activator -Xms512M -Xmx512M run
activator -mem 512 -J-server run //this doesn't run
env JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"  &&  activator run 
env JAVA_OPTS="-mem 512" &&  activator run 
env JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MetaspaceSize=64M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512M"  &&  activator run 
env JAVA_OPTS="-DX:MetaspaceSize=64m -DX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m"  &&  activator run
```

When using activator -mem 512 run or activator -mem 512 -J-server run I get the following error.

```
[warn] The `-` command is deprecated in favor of `onFailure` and will be removed in 0.14.0
[error] Expected letter
[error] Expected symbol
[error] Expected '!'
[error] Expected '+'
[error] Expected '++'
[error] Expected 'debug'
[error] Expected 'info'
[error] Expected 'warn'
[error] Expected 'error'
[error] Expected ';'
[error] Expected end of input.
[error] Expected '--'
[error] Expected 'show'
[error] Expected 'all'
[error] Expected '*'
[error] Expected '{'
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected key
[error] Expected '-'
[error] 512
[error] ^
[error] Not a valid command: mem (similar: set)
[error] Not a valid project ID: mem
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: mem (similar: name, makePom, make-pom)
[error] mem
[error]    ^
```

Am I doing this on the wrong way?

Comment: `activator -mem 512 run` should work... What error do you get? If you are using a unix system, try to run `ps xau | grep activator` to see if the memory values are passed correctly (you should see a `-Xmx512m` there)

Comment: @Salem I'm on windows. I added the error message in the question description. Not a valid key: mem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by using **SET** instead **ENV** and removing double quotes.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64m -Xmx512m &&  activator run
```

=)